# Update database when confirm is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I know how to update the database when the button is clicked (`if (isset($_POST[....`) I know how to ask the user whether he wants to submit or not a form with javascript. But I do not know how to ask the user this, and if he/she clicks on the confirming option, the database is updated.

All I can think about is mixing php and javascript but this does not sound good to me so I would be really pleased if you can help me with this problem.

Thank you for your time

I have tryed the following:

```
<button name="submit_text" onclick="pregunta()">Submit text</button>

  <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit_text'])) {

        $sql="UPDATE .......

        mysqli_query($db,$sql);

        header("Refresh:0");

        mysqli_close($db);
    }
  ?>

  <script language="JavaScript"> 
function pregunta(){ 
    if (confirm('El texto traducido se enviará al cliente. ¿Está seguro?')){ 
       return true; 
    } else {
       return false;
    }
} 
</script>
```

But the php will be executed even the button clicked is No

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far

Comment: <form onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');">

Comment: Thank you for your time but I want to submit the form and update the database at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `confirm()` method to request confirmation from the user. It returns a boolean which you can use to control the logic flow. Try this:

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the form?'))
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. And then how I would do it to execute or not the mysql declarations I have got, depending on the Accept or Decline button that the user clicked?

Comment: If the user clicks OK to this then the form will be submit as usual. You can then run the PHP code which you stated you already knew how to do

Comment: But if the user clicks on NO, how would I do it NOT to run the php code?

Comment: That's exactly what the code above does. If you click Cancel, then the form won't be submit, hence the PHP won't be executed.

Comment: Thank you, I understood how it works. Did not sleep any hours... :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)